# Django HTMLForms AttributeError AttributeError: module 'polls.views' has no attribute 'index'

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django to create a simple HTML input page, right now I am just using the tutorial for Django Forms but I get the error AttributeError: module 'polls.views' has no attribute 'index'

Here are all the relevant files:

This is where the Error is happening:

```
$ mysite/polls/urls.py

from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

This is views.py:

```
$ polls/views.py
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import NameForm

def get_name(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = NameForm()

    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```

and this is forms.py

```
$ /polls/forms.py
from Django import forms

class NameForm(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=100)
```

Here is name.html:

```
$ /polls/name.html
<html>
  <form action="/your-name/" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form }}
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
<html>
```

I am so confused as to why this is happening because when I used it with the *Writing your first Django app tutorial* it worked but when I use a form it doesn't

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view name is not `index` but `get_name`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.get_name, name='index'),
]
```

Comment: Thank you this fixed the first problem but now I get `ImportError: cannot import name 'views' from 'mysite'`

Comment: Never mind thsi worked i just changed `from . import views` to `from polls import views` thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

Your polls/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'polls' # add this line

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Comment: Now I get an error saying cannot import views from mysite so  I changed from . import views to from polls import views but I still get the views has no attribute index error. Any more ideas?

Comment: Please add your html file to your question

Comment: You must be added this line to your `polls/urls.py`. You did it correctly ?

Comment: I have added my HTML file

Comment: Yes I added it 
```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'polls' # add this line

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```



Returns error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'views' from 'mysite'